# Neighbour John saw cat Whiskers near pharmacy GBN when car Mercedes was there

Tags: grammar, nouns

Are there any restrictions as to which title nouns can be placed before proper names?

How correct is this sentence:

'Neighbour John saw cat Whiskers near pharmacy GBN when car Mercedes was there.'

Comment: My neighbor John saw the cat Whiskers near the phramacy GBM when a Mercedes was there.

Comment: Yes, but I'd hafta say _the GBN pharmacy_, or just _GBN_. Generally nouns don't aggregate like that; and some have other needs, like _neighbour_, which is a relational word like _cousin_ and needs a possessor. And cars are never referred to as "car Mercedes". If you know it's a Mercedes, you know it's a car.

Comment: Or 'Whiskers the cat'.

Comment: @KateBunting What difference does it make in terms of meaning, register, style?

Comment: 'Neighbour John saw cat Whiskers near pharmacy GBN when car Mercedes was there.'  Sounds like something intended for a computer (or produced by a computer).

Comment: I suggested it because we often say '[Name] the [description]' in English - Felix the Cat, Attila the Hun, Alexander the Great...

Comment: This comes across as headlinese (though 'car Mercedes' is _very_ unidiomatic), stilted and unidiomatic in conversation and not too hot in prose.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would the article change your perception in "the organization Greenpeace", "the ballet Swan Lake", "the novel Don Quixote", "the cheese Camembert"?

Comment: **the organzation Greenpeace** is an appositive construction and is idiomatic.  It is neither a title nor a role, nor a bare noun.

Comment: @TimR "the cheese Camembert" is an appositive construction too, isn't it? How idiomatic is it?

Comment: You would only say 'the cheese Camembert' when speaking to someone who was unlikely to know that Camembert is a type of cheese.

Comment: @KateBunting   Or if there were such a thing as Camembert, the rock opera, and you were disambiguating.

Comment: @waterlily99  Yes, the others were appositives as well. It is not clear from your question ("which title nouns") whether you recognize that not all nouns can serve as "titles", though from your excellent command of the language it seems  very unlikely that you would not know that fact.

Comment: With "the organization Greenpeace", "the ballet Swan Lake", and "the novel Don Quixote", I expect either no prior verbal context ('The ballet _Swan Lake_ is being performed in Bristol next month'), or prior context inviting precising (Bristol is famous for its focus on the arts; the ballet _Swan Lake_ is being performed there next month, for instance'. I'd never expect to see/hear 'the cheese Camembert'; possibly 'Camembert (the cheese) ...' to differentiate it from the town.

Comment: @KateBunting  What enabled you to form such precise and finely articulated perceptions of subtleties in very specific contexts?

Comment: Long experience of reading and using English!

Comment: @TimR I am just yet to find a more or less comprehensive list of nouns that can be used in such a role, along with the idiomaticity markers.

Comment: I doubt that such a list exists.

Comment: @waterlily99 The list would become outdated, since the bare noun that comes before a proper name doesn't have to be a widely recognized word like "President" but can be any word that is a role in any domain, and new domains are always being added. "*Midfielder* Kevin De Bruyne has torn his achilles tendon" and now we can also say "*Seeker* Harry Potter was ejected from the match";  words also fall out of use for a variety of reasons and are replaced with new ones; "Stewardess" is now "Flight Attendant", for example. All you need to do is ask: Is that noun a recognized *role*?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is there at least a rough classification of the categories of restrictive appositives used outside of journalese? You have probably never heard "the wine Merlot"  or "the horse Valyra", have you?

Comment: For starters, you often wouldn't use 'the N₁N₂' where N₂ would normally be preceded by an indefinite article when an unspecified specimen ('My neighbour John saw Whiskers the cat near a local Boots chemist's when there was a Mercedes parked outside' is idiomatic: not  Chemist's Boots or car Mercedes). 'The mercedes car' / 'the Deltic locomotive' are different, reversals. // And in the example here, 'Neighbour John' and 'cat Whiskers' are unidiomatic. As Tim says, domain / occupation N₁s are typical, but here there is also an overlap with titles (Professor Plum; Sister Stephanie ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - as a long time fan of the Class 55 (D9000 class) locomotive, I would mention that 'Deltic' also refers to the Napier Diesel engine with a triangular arrangement of cylinders that also powered naval boats (still used in the Royal Navy Hunt class minesweepers) and also the New York City Fire Department's one-of-a-kind "Super Pumper System". This was a very-high-volume trailer-mounted fire pump with a separate tender.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - sorry, I'm a railway enthusiast when I'm not here

Comment: 'The locomotive _Mallard_ broke down' and 'the Deltic locomotive broke down' are significantly different. The first uses a precising/identifying apposition, the second a classifying premodifying attributive (and proper) noun.

Answer (score 1):

A title or role can appear before proper nouns

> Mayor Jones was present, along with Congressman Smith, Reverend Wilkins, and District Attorney Alice Luna.
>
> Neighbor John and pet Whiskers were seen peeping through the window of the Dollar Store, John at the discount cigarettes and Whiskers at some tins of tuna.
>
> Brother Samuel gave a beautiful rendition of Amazing Grace.
>
> Favorite "Fightin' Chance" had the post position in the race but finished last.
>
> Best Man John Smith gave a speech about the bridegroom's previous failed romantic relationships, which some found very funny while others where quite aghast.
>
> Big Cheese Johnny LaRue sat down at a table with three of his top henchmen.

"role" is a fairly flexible thing.  Since every stakes race has an odds-on favorite,  "favorite" can suffice as a role, especially to those who frequent the race-track to bet on the thoroughbreds, though there may be some speakers with no experience of that demimonde for whom the usage might sound totally off or marginal.

Same with "neighbor".  If you're someone who says or hears "Howdy, neighbor" on a regular basis, then you'll have no trouble parsing "Neighbor John" as a role. But if you don't think of neighbor as being a role in a local context, that could strike you as marginal.

Comment: I think grammatically this is correct, but giving someone a title of "Neighbor" [name] feels out of place to me. I am more accustomed to hearing "My neighbor John" or "John, my neighbor."

Answer (score 0):

The rule is something like this: *the simple noun must be the role it plays or the relationship it has  --either in that specific context or in the world in general-- and the proper noun must be the *given name* of the noun*.

In more detail:

The noun must describe the role that it plays or the relationship it has. "*Neighbour*" is a relationship that John has relative to the speaker, but "*cat*" is neither a role nor a relationship, which is why in TimR's answer, he replaced "*cat*" with "*pet*" -- "*pet*" is a relationship. "*Car*" is also neither a role nor a relationship.

The proper noun following the noun must be the name of that individual noun, like "*neighbour John*", where "*John*" is the name of that particular neighbour. This means "*car Mercedes*" doesn't work unless the owner of the car named it "Mercedes", regardless of it's actual make.